# Using a InputText at same time as ListBox | PySimpleGUI | Python

Tags: python, pysimplegui

[Click here to see my problem](https://youtube.com/shorts/OiERK7iVG_w),

1: I want to see the filtered list after typing in the InputText immediately, for some reason it only updates on the second character

2: I want to be able to use the search box even after selecting an option in the list

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
if event == '-search-term-':
    SearchTerm = values['-search-term-']
    SearchTerm.replace("['", "")
    SearchTerm.replace("']", "")
  
    if values[event]:
    
      for i in alllist:
        if SearchTerm in i:
          if i not in matchlist:
            matchlist.append(i)
            outlist = sorted(matchlist)
            window.Element('-scr-lib-list-').Update(values=outlist)
              
        if SearchTerm not in i:
          if i in matchlist:
            matchlist.remove(i)
            outlist = matchlist
            window.Element('-scr-lib-list-').Update(values=outlist)
          
          outlist = sorted(matchlist)
          window.Element('-scr-lib-list-').Update(values=outlist)
          
    else:
      out = sorted(alllist)
      window.Element('-scr-lib-list-').Update(values=out)
```

Comment: Need your layout and Window creation.  Can you post a working program?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the demo code to update the values of a `Listbox` element under event from a Input element. It filter the items in list by the content of the Input element.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

font = ('Courier New', 11)
sg.set_options(font=font)
sg.theme('DarkBlue4')

all_files = [
    '01 Whetting Your Appetite.pptx',
    '02 Using the Python Interpreter.pptx',
    '03 An Informal Introduction to Python.pptx',
    '04 More Control Flow Tools.pptx',
    '05 Data Structures.pptx',
    '06 Modules.pptx',
    '07 Input and Output.pptx',
    '08 Errors and Exceptions.pptx',
    '09 Classes.pptx',
    '10 Brief Tour of the Standard Library.pptx',
    '11 Virtual Environments and Packages.pptx',
    '12 What Now.pptx',
    '13 Interactive Input Editing and History Substitution.pptx',
    '14 Representation Error.日心pptx',
]

width = max(map(len, all_files))

layout = [
    [sg.Input('', expand_x=True, enable_events=True, key='-INPUT-')],
    [sg.Listbox(all_files, size=(width, 7), enable_events=True, key='-LISTBOX-')],
]
window = sg.Window('File Filter', layout, finalize=True)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break
    elif event == '-INPUT-':
        string = values['-INPUT-'].lower()
        if string:
            files = [file for file in all_files if string in file.lower()]
        else:
            files = all_files[:]
        window['-LISTBOX-'].update(files)
    elif event == '-LISTBOX-':
        filename = values['-LISTBOX-'][0]
        print(filename)

window.close()
```